# Что лушче wpf или asp.net и когда?

Tags: asp.net, c#, wpf, веб-программирование

Я новичок в wpf и в asp, но я слышал в лекции, что с помощью wpf можно создавать приложения для браузера. Т.е. если я правильно понял, то на wpf можно делать web страницы. Соответственно возник вопрос, чем он лучше или хуже asp, и когда, что лучше использовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WPF  для web? Что-то вы путаете. WPF используется для создания десктопных приложений. Возможно, есть какие-то грязные хаки, позволяющие использовать эту технологию в веб-разработке, но это заведомо проигрышный вариант по сравнению с ASP.NT изначально заточенным   под web-разработку. Возможно, вы имели в виду Silverlight, впрочем, это несколько иная технология, хоть и связанная с WPF. Однако противопоставлять Silverlight ASP.NET'у несколько неверно. Да и к  тому же MS уже объявляла о планах свернуть работу над Silverlight.

Comment: +1.

Дополню лишь, что ASP.NET — технология серверная, а Silverlight работает на клиентской стороне.

Comment: Есть возможность сделать XAML Browser Application, еще одна из интересных мертвых идей. Но не стоит.